# How to get a String to Float with Conversion and use Them for Cordinates

Tags: c#

Hello Community im trying to learn C# but this Problems makes me Crazy,
Im Trying to Read Cordinates from a TXT File and split them into 3.
And then im tried to convert them to Float because for Cordinates i need Float Right?

Code First Try

```
            foreach (string CORDS in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"/RAGEMP/server-files/blips/hospital/hospitalcords.txt"))
        { 
            float[] floatData = Array.ConvertAll(CORDS.Split(','), float.Parse);
            float float1 = floatData[0];
            float float2 = floatData[1];
            float float3 = floatData[2];
            Blip Hospital = NAPI.Blip.CreateBlip(153, new Vector3(float1,float2,float3), 0.5f, 1, "Hospital"); ;
            NAPI.Blip.SetBlipShortRange(Hospital, true);
        }
```

Second Try

```
            foreach (string CORDS in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"/RAGEMP/server-files/blips/hospital/hospitalcords.txt"))
        {
            string[] split = CORDS.Split(',');
            float flt1 = float.Parse(split[0]); 
            float flt2 = float.Parse(split[1]);
            float flt3 = float.Parse(split[2]);
            Blip Hospital = NAPI.Blip.CreateBlip(153, new Vector3(flt1, flt2, flt3), 0.5f, 1, "Hospital"); ;
            NAPI.Blip.SetBlipShortRange(Hospital, true);
        }
```

but not one of them worked and im trying to Convert them into a Float was because im Trying to Learn C# with a Framework (RageMP) for GTA 5 Servers and the Vector needs cordinates and with a String i cant use them. (Please be friendly to a beginner im started last Week :D)

**Text from the readed File**

```
290.8559, -589.8578, 42.764145
```

**Picture of the Warning:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Fl8.png)

Comment: Note that float.Parse or Double.Parse depends on the current `CultureInfo` for the interpretation of periods `.` in the strings. I can see in your screenshot, that you are from Germany? In this case try to use `CultureInfo` => `float.Parse(split[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing it self should work fine - tried your code - but you may need to specify a CultureInfo
try

`float.Parse(split[0],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Parsing in .net unfortunally usually localized and dependent on language of the user that runs the program
e.g. for me or you with german system language it will only parse numbers using "," as decimal point right

Maybe thats your problem

if not maybe try

```
   var cordList = text.Split(',').Select(item => float.Parse(item.Trim(),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
   var pos = new Vector3(cordList[0], cordList[1], cordList[2]);
```

not sure if the left over spaces could result in errors while parsing

Comment: Yes that solved my Problem thank you very much i´ve tried 100 things 2 Days long and nothing worked, that was a little but Important thing for my Code ^^. But the Important thing about your Answer was i learned something Thank you !    ( And Sorry for my English i hope its good enough to Understand what i mean)